# Allow Remote Desktop through Putty ssh connection

Tags: remote-desktop, putty, tunnel

There are several questions on SuperUser about how to allow a Remote Desktop connection from a Windows Computer to another Windows Computer through an ssh tunnel like this:

1. ssh: local Windows -> putty -> ssh server
2. Remote Desktop: local Windows -> ssh tunnel -> ssh server -> remote Windows

I have done this before and it works fine.

What I want to do now is slightly different:

I want to connect to a remote Windows computer through an ssh connection initiated by that remote computer.

1. ssh: remote Windows -> putty -> ssh server
2. Remote Desktop: Local Windows -> ssh server -> ssh tunnel -> remote Windows

Unfortunately I cannot figure out what exactly I need to configure to get an ssh tunnel that I can use this way.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want.  Are you saying you want to somehow have the remote computer SSH into your local computer and set up a tunnel so that you can then RDP from the local computer to the remote computer via that tunnel?

Comment: I want the remote computer ssh into a linux ssh server in my LAN. It should set up a tunnel that I can then use to connect to it via Remote Desktop from my local computer.

Comment: Does your local computer run SSH server?

Comment: No, it's not even always the same computer. I might want to connect to the remote computer from any Windows computer on the LAN. That's why I want to use an (existing) ssh server running on a Linux computer as intermediary.

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer.

Comment: You could setup a script on the remote server to establish the tunnel, but you'd need a way to trigger the script still.

Comment: @kicken Yes, exactly. You need an *agent* there to open the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a tunnel from a remote machine on an arbitrary other machine.

That would be a terrible security hole.

Comment: Actually that is what the first example does: It opens a tunnel to the ssh server which then forwards an RD-connection to an arbitrary machine on the LAN. And it works.

Comment: What I want to do is basically create a tunnel that can be connected to in the other direction. I'm sure that this is possible too.

Comment: No it's not. If you are referring to: *"ssh: local Windows -> putty -> ssh server"* --- It opens an outgoing tunnel from the local machine (where you run the SSH client) to the SSH machine, where SSH servers runs to which you are authenticated, which further connects to the third (arbitrary) machine. The first two machines run a software which you control. The third machine has no active participation of the tunnel, it only accept an incoming connection, as any other connection (without even knowing it comes from a tunnel).

Comment: While what you want is for the the third (arbitrary) machine to open the outgoing tunnel. That's not possible, you have no control over that machine.

Comment: But I have: I am sitting right in front of it.

Comment: And before you ask: Somebody else is sitting in front of the remote machine and creates the tunnel using Putty.

Comment: What I mean is that the remote computer (that you want to initiate the tunnel - for reasons you didn't explain) does not have a control over the local machine.